# Single-page webpages, Asp.net MVC and authentication

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, authentication

I am familiar with how forms authentication works with ASP.NET MVC; it's not too difficult.  But I am somewhat uncertain how authentication works with single-page web applications.   Of course I can handle the initial login with a single-page app, since there will be a postback and i can do the standard forms authentication.  But after that i will use ajax to access further webpage content.

My thought was to implement an interval function with Jquery to fire every 20 minutes or so which would ask for a password to re-authenticate.  What is the "best practice" for doing authentication for asp.net MVC single page web apps?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use form authentication as well. The ajax requests go through the same pipeline as full page postabacks because they are just plain HTTP requests with different content type and payload. So once you authenticate the user and the authentication cookie is created then it would be transferred on the server. Thus the server will check it in a standard way. The only thing you need to handle is the redirect to the login page for not authenticated users. You can handle this issue on client side (the http redirects are not handled by XHR requests by default but you can write a custom code to handle them). Return a 401 http status code for ajax requests:

```
    public class AuthorizeAjaxAttribute : AuthorizeAttribute
    {    
        protected override void HandleUnauthorizedRequest(AuthorizationContext filterContext)
        {
            if (filterContext.RequestContext.HttpContext.Request.IsAjaxRequest() &&
                // angular.js requests
                filterContext.RequestContext.HttpContext.Request.ContentType == "application/json" ||
                filterContext.RequestContext.HttpContext.Request.ContentType == "application/xml" ||
               )
            {
                // ajax request returns HTTP 401 (Unauthorized) status code
                filterContext.Result = new Http401Result();
            }
            else
            {
                // standard behavior - redirect to login page
                base.HandleUnauthorizedRequest(filterContext);
            }
        }
    }
```

Then handle it on client side (depends on your client side framework):

```
$(document).ajaxError(function (event, jqxhr, settings, exception) {
    if (jqxhr.status == 401) { //Forbidden, go to login
        //Use a reload, WIF will redirect to Login
        location.url = "/Account/Login";
    }
});
```

Comment: Ah ok i think i've got it!  I am going to work up some code and I will post the results here.  The only thing is that, after the user has logged in the first time, I want to avoid redirecting away from the single-page (in case of needing to RE-authenticate after initial login).  But is seems that would be easily accomplished from what you are telling me.  Many thanks for pointing me in the right direction here!